# Why does this recurring function fire twice per input?

Tags: recursion, range, elixir

When executing:

```
def guess(a..b) do
  IO.puts "In rn = #{a}..#{b}"
  guess(a..b, IO.getn("Is it greater than #{div(a + b, 2)} ? : ", 1) |> String.upcase == "Y")
end
def guess(a..b, true) do
  guess(div(a + b, 2)..b)
end
def guess(a..b, false) do
  guess(a..div(a + b, 2))
end
```

Results:

```
iex(1)> Test.guess(1..10)
  1 In rn = 1..10
  2 Is it greater than 5 ? : y
  3 In rn = 5..10
  4 Is it greater than 7 ? :
  5 In rn = 5..7
  6 Is it greater than 6 ? : n
  7 In rn = 5..6
  8 Is it greater than 5 ? :
  9 In rn = 5..5
 10 Is it greater than 5 ? : y
 11 In rn = 5..5
 12 Is it greater than 5 ? :
 13 In rn = 5..5
 14 Is it greater than 5 ? :
```

---

iex did not wait for user input on lines 4, 8, & 12 - after receiving an input, it appears to run through the loop twice.

Why might that be?

---

**Solved:**

Apparently, something weird happens with IO.getn when used in this manner - perhaps reading "Y" as a byte, and "enter" as a separate byte. Replacing IO.gets and no character count seems to fix the problem. Alternatively, isolating the getn method call might keep this issue from occurring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. When in the terminal, `IO.getn/1` only returns the bytes after you enter a new line, which means if you are reading byte per byte recursively, you are going to receive two bytes, one for the user command and another for the new line. `IO.gets/1` is the way to go here.